# How long can we safely store cold brew concentrate?

Tags: storage, cold-brew

How long can we store cold brew? 
Does storing cold brew for a week or more affect its taste or texture provided that we use good grinding beans and make it under proper ratio?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How long will cold brew keep?](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/1872/how-long-will-cold-brew-keep)

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, if you have sanitised your equipment properly you should get three to four weeks when storing cold brew in a ready-to-drink ratio in the fridge. My feeling is that concentrate would probably have a longer shelf life, but by how much I can't really say.

The taste will change over time depending on how well filtered the cold brew is. If it is only lightly strained or filtered, a lot of coffee solids will remain in the brew and make it stronger/bolder over time (sometimes it can be quite nice). If it is well filtered and clear, then the flavour will be pretty consistent until it starts to go sour or bad.