# What is the coffee & water ratio when cold brewing?

Tags: cold-brew

What is the proper coffee to water ratio for a cold brew? I did mine with 100grams of coffee (an Ethiopian light roast) and a liter of water, and brewed for about 12 hours. It tasted good to me, but my friends said it's too acidic for them, hence I find it acidic in a way that the sweetness is present and with clean finish.

Comment: You should first study other questions with the tag [tag:cold-brew] here.

Comment: Hello and welcome to [coffee.se]. If [the other question](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/481/whats-the-recommended-coffee-to-water-ratio-for-cold-brew) doesn't answer your question, ask another! See also [this question](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/1562/what-roast-level-is-recommended-for-cold-brew) about roast level considerations, which can relate to acidity, and how [cold brewing differs from hot-brew](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/96/how-will-cold-brewed-coffee-differ-from-traditional-hot-water-extraction-metho). Welcome to [se]!

Answer (score 1):

It depends where you look. When you create the concentrate some people say 1:2, coffee and water, some say 1:1. It really depends on how you like it.

Comment: Are those ratios by weight or by volume?

Comment: Theses ratios are by weight.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your target, but you can try various combinations, until you and your friends find the "right" balance.

The coffee-to-water ratio does not influence much acidity, in my experience. Cold-brew coffee is usually more acidic.

You could try another roast. Darker roasts should bring more strength to the taste, and perhaps counter-balance the acidic aspect enough.

As mentioned in answer and comments, it depends on your actual target, and related questions here can give you ideas.