# What are good ratios for cold brewing coffee?

Tags: cold-brew

I'm using a mason jar + inserted filter method to brew cold brew concentrate. My normal method is 2L water per 110 grams of coffee, left in the fridge for 24 to 48 hours. Is this good for a concentrate or should I adjust my ratios/time/temperature? I've heard that room temperature is better, but I haven't seen anything to back that up. Seems like it would be better to maintain lower temp for bacteria. Any advice?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the coffee & water ratio when cold brewing?](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/2404/what-is-the-coffee-water-ratio-when-cold-brewing)

Comment: Experiment and find what **you** like.

Comment: Welcome! This post contains two different questions, one about rations (which already has answers [here](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/481/whats-the-recommended-coffee-to-water-ratio-for-cold-brew)) and one about food safety. The SE  format is designed for _one_ question per post, the [tour], the [help], and especially [ask] should explain more. It would be good if you could [edit] your post to choose _one_ question. As it stands, it may be closed as duplicate by the community.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the recommended coffee to water ratio for cold brew?](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/481/whats-the-recommended-coffee-to-water-ratio-for-cold-brew)

Answer (score 2):

> According to Food52, the optimal cold brew coffee ratio is 3/4 cup
>   coarsely ground coffee to every four cups of cold water

[Psst… We've Figured Out the Perfect Cold Brew Coffee Ratio](https://www.mydomaine.com/cold-brew-coffee-ratio#:~:text=According%20to%20Food52%2C%20the%20optimal,cold%2Dbrew%20coffee%20at%20home.)